# PowerPoint finish looping animation on Click

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I have a number of images on one slide. Each has an animation that moves it from its start location to its finish location. I want that to happen until I Click to advance, at which point it should begin animating the next picture.

This works, however, the problem is when I click to advance from Picture 1 to Picture 2, Picture 1 gets left whereever it was in its animation path at the moment I clicked, then begins the Picture 2 animation. This leaves Picture 1 "out of place" if I don't click at the exact right moment. I would like Picture 1 to always get to its final location (i.e. finish the current loop iteration) after I click, then begin the Picture 2 animation.

I don't want to hard-code the number of loop repeats because I want to be able to talk about the movement of each picture without having to "hardcode" the amount of time I have to speak.

I can of course get it to work if I time each click perfectly, but I don't' want to rely on 100% timing accuracy with the clicks. It just won't happen.

So essentially, when I click, I want to advance to animating the next picture, but also ensure the previous picture is left in its final position.

Comment: Based on getting no responses, I'm guessing this is not something that's possible.  I've just done my animations differently in the end.

Comment: Maybe add a path to picture 1, then a path to picture 2 set to start on a mouse click then a new path on picture1 set to start with previous (i.e. the animation on Picture 2) Maybe show us what you have so far? It's not clear to me what you mean by loop in this case

Comment: Very interesting @cybernetic.nomad.  I'm finished now, but it adds a lot of complexity.  But it's a good idea and I will try along those lines in future!  Thanks!